# Identify swt widget on mouse event

Tags: java, swt

I have a function that catches mouse up events. In there i can get the reference to the widget but i do not have any data to identify what widget was actually pressed:

```
@Override
public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
    Control c = (Control) e.widget;
}
```

What is the correct way to add some kind of an id to the widget which i can check on this event to identify what widget was pressed?

I tried using setData() but im not sure this is correct?

```
widget.setData("myfield");
```

and later:

```
if("myfield".equals(e.widget.getData)){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setData` is the usual way but use the

```
Widget.setData("key", data);

Object data = Widget.getData("key");
```

methods. where "key" is something that is unique to your code. This will stop any clash with other code using the widget data.